# 1D transverse-field Ising model - what is the difference between its classical and quantum treatment?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ising-model, lattice-model, spin-chains

The 1D [transverse field Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse-field_Ising_model):
$$ H(\sigma)=-J\sum_{i\in Z} \sigma^x_i \sigma^x_{i+1} -h \sum_{i \in Z} \sigma^z_i$$
is usually solved in quantum way, but we can also solve it classically - parametrize angles of spins $\sigma^x_i = \cos(\alpha_i), \sigma^z_i=\sin(\alpha_i)$ and use **Boltzmann ensemble of sequences of spin angles**:
$$\textrm{Pr}(\sigma)\propto \exp(-H(\sigma)) \qquad \textrm{for} \qquad \sigma = ((\cos(\alpha_i),\sin(\alpha_i)))_{i\in Z}$$
getting Markov process of angles, which can be easily approximated with [Maximal Entropy Random Walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_entropy_random_walk), for example getting below joint distributions for $(\alpha_i, \alpha_{i+1})\in [0,2\pi]^2$ for various parameters (Section III [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.13300)):

[image]

As intuition suggests, there is some thermal wobbling of spin directions: (anti)aligned for dominating $J$, in $x$ axis for dominating $h$.

However, in quantum approaches there are only considered spins in four directions: $|\leftarrow \rangle,|\rightarrow \rangle,|\uparrow \rangle,|\downarrow \rangle$, so should we imagine that intermediate angles are obtained by superposition? Should there be thermal wobbling of spin directions as in densities above?

What are the differences in interpretation and predictions between such looking natural classical treatment and the quantum one?

Comment: I have found similar 2006 paper "Classical Ising chain in transverse field": https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304885306016295 saying that classical and quantum predictions are quite similar. Classical is much simpler to calculate - it would be great to get a deeper understanding of their differences, compare with modern experiments like 2019 https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-019-1070-1

Comment: I don't understand why you are saying the quantum model only considers the spin in four directions. One can allow the spin to "point" in any direction (on average anyways; the "direction" of a quantum spin-1/2 isn't well-defined).