# Why Can Electrons be Modelled as Classical Spins?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, angular-momentum, electrons, ising-model, spin-models

Although electrons are spin $1/2$ particles described by the Pauli matrices, the Ising model treats electrons as classical spins. As a result, the Ising model does not describe anything physical, but its results are good enough to approximate many properties of materials. Why can such a model which treats a purely quantum mechanical effect as a classical one describe physical systems well? Is there a reason why we can approximately treat the electron spins as classical spins?

Comment: Because that is how the math works out.

Comment: @JonCuster Are you saying that the only reason is because the predictions of the theory match with experiment? I was wondering if there were certain conditions that enable us to approximate the spins as classical ones.

Comment: conservation of angular momentum? Intrinsic spins were assigned in order to have conservation of angular momentum at the quantum level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an interesting post here which I think answers this question: [What is the difference between classical and quantum Ising model?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273748/what-is-the-difference-between-classical-and-quantum-ising-model)

For the Ising model specifically, the post says that the dynamics are equivalent to that of the classical problem because all the operators commute with each other.